# Running netsh from using Inno Setup Exec()

Tags: inno-setup, netsh

I'm trying to create Windows Firewall rule during installation and I'm having trouble understanding how my command is formatted incorrectly. The error returned in `ResultCode` is "Incorrect Function"

```pascal
procedure OpenFirewall;
var
  WindowsVersion: Integer;
  ResultCode: Integer;
  W7Command: String;
  WXPCommand: String;
begin
  WXPCommand := 'netsh firewall add portopening TCP 12345 "MyApp"'
  W7Command := 'netsh advfirewall add rule name="MyApp" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=12345';
  WindowsVersion := GetWindowsVersion();
  case WindowsVersion of
    5:
    begin
      Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C ' + WXPCommand, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
    end;
    6:
    begin
      Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/C ' + W7Command, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
      Log(SysErrorMessage(ResultCode));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `ResultCode` contains a system error, only if the `Exec` returns `False` (indicating a failure to start a process). If the `Exec` succeeds to start the process, the `ResultCode` contains an exit code of the process. What is likely your case. You cannot pass the exit code to `SysErrorMessage`.

Quoting [`Exec` documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec):

> If True is returned and Wait is ewWaitUntilTerminated then ResultCode returns the exit code of the process. If False is returned then ResultCode specifies the error that occurred. Use SysErrorMessage(ResultCode) to get a description of the error.

---

The actual problem is your syntax of `netsh`.

You are missing a `firewall` keyword after the `advfirewall`.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule ...
```

See [Netsh AdvFirewall Firewall Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd734783(v=ws.10)).

*Did you even bother to test the command from command-line first?*

---

Side notes:

- Check the return value of `Exec`
- No need to start `netsh.exe` via `cmd.exe`
- What about other Windows versions?